# How to execute an external command and capture its output in perl6?

Tags: process, raku, rakudo

How can I execute an external command and capture its output in Perl6?

Perl5-style back-ticks don't seem to work:

```
> my $results = `ls`;
Confused at line 1, near "my $results"
```

[Synopsis 16](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S16.html) documents the *run* method, but this returns the exit status rather than the output from stdout.

I'm using the Rakudo implementation (rakudo-star-2010.12).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use qqx or qx instead, e.g.:

```
> my $results = qqx{ls};
```

Larry Wall [answered](http://markmail.org/message/zvn2hul6irggtrde) an equivalent question on a mailing list:

> [...]
>
> : What replaces backtick or qx{} ?
>
> qqx[] or qq:x[] would be the exact
>   equivalent.  qx[] or q:x[] would be
>   the same with single-quote semantics. 
>   (There are probably no backticks for
>   that purpose since we're reserving `
>   for user-defined stuff, and because
>   backticks are visually difficult to
>   tell from single quotes in many
>   fonts.)

Comment: I found the answer just before posting the question, but posted it anyway in case it's useful to others.

Answer (score 5):

As of Jan 2015:

[Recently verified tutorial page](http://perl6maven.com/tutorial/running-external-commands-from-perl6)

[Recent Perl 6 advent page](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/quoting-on-steroids/)

[Recent discussion of rationalizing what gets returned by what](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/search/?nick=&q=proc%3A%3Astatus)

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done safely (without touching a shell) using `run()` with the `out` parameter:

```
my $proc = run 'ls', q!/tmp/"This" is an ugly name, isn't it?/!, :out;
my $output = $proc.out.slurp-rest;
```

More details available in the [`Proc` class](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Proc).